# Class files not getting generated after building the project in RAD 7.5?

Tags: eclipse, rad

Even after building the project I am unable to see any bin folder and hence any class file.

Tried adding the project to source in Java build path also but the problem is still same. What can be the solution?

Comment: If you are using the Package Explorer view (or Project Explorer) they don't show the 'bin' folder

Comment: I am looking for the class file at the same path(bin instead of src) in my system. I know where it should be but not getting it.